# How to test if a MySQL query was successful in modifying database table data?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, rows-affected

I have the following simple php code snippet, which will, when called, delete a relevant article from a database. The result is passed to a javascript function, which will update the page via AJAX. I would like to return the string `false` if the query fails, as I've below.

```
if($cmd=="deleterec"){
    $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM AUCTIONS1 WHERE ARTICLE_NO = ?";
    if ($delRecord = $con->prepare($deleteQuery)) {
        $delRecord->bind_param("s", $pk);
        $delRecord->execute();
        $delRecord->close();
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

I would like to know what I have missed and the correct way to check if a query was successful or not.

Comment: please elaborate with more details about why it's apparently not working at the moment, and show the Javascript code too.

Comment: Stupid questions first -- $con is a valid connection, right?

Comment: yup, it sure is.

Alnitak, javascript code is pasted, however the page never returns 'false' so I don't think it is a javascript problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [mysqli->affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_affected_rows) for checking if the query was successful (or you could use [mysqli_stmt->execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)'s result value).

Taking your example, and modifying nothing but for the above:

```
if($cmd=="deleterec") {
    $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM AUCTIONS1 WHERE ARTICLE_NO = ?";
    
    if ($delRecord = $con->prepare($deleteQuery)) {
        $delRecord->bind_param("s", $pk);
        $delRecord->execute();
    
    
        if ($delRecord->affected_rows > 0) {
            echo "true";
        } else {
            echo "false";
        }

        $delRecord->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `> 0` is not necessary for this case; a truthy/falsey check is all that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently only checking whether the SQL statement is correctly prepared, you're not checking whether it actually deleted the record.

Try:

```
...
echo ($delRecord->affected_rows > 0) ? 'true' : 'false';
$delRecord->close();
```

That doesn't address whether you're correctly checking the result string in your Javascript code - if that's a problem we'll need more information.

Comment: `> 0` is not necessary for this case; a truthy/falsey check is all that is needed.

Comment: @mickmackusa and is arguably a bad practise;  Many coding standards would prohibit such an implicit coercion of an integer value into a boolean.

Comment: Could you please link me to such documented standards so that I can read up on it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the return value of [`mysqli_stmt->execute()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) to see if the query was executed successful.

Comment: ...but of course this doesn't indicate if the database table was changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($cmd=="deleterec"){
    $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM AUCTIONS1 WHERE ARTICLE_NO = ?";
    $delRecord = $con->prepare($deleteQuery);
    if ( $delRecord === false ) {
        echo "false";
    }

    $delRecord->bind_param("s", $pk);
    if ( $delRecord->execute() ) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
    $delRecord->close();
}
```

Checking `prepare()` could be left out because the query is fixed and should be working (unless there is an error on the server side). `execute()` returns true, if the query was executed successful. Using `affected_rows()` can be misleading because perhaps there was no item to delete and therefore `affected_rows()` whould return `0`. Nontheless the query was successfully executed.

Answer (score -1):

```
function run_query($query,$conn,$dbname){
   $conn->select_db($dbname);
   if($result = $conn->query($query)){
     return $result; 
   }
   else{
     echo 'error ';
     exit();
   }
```

}

run_query() accepts three parameters, the query, connection, and DB. will through an error if the query was unsuccessful, else result object will be returned.